# How to get parents div clicked item element and class on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question is asked many times but they didn't help me.

I have scenario, like I clicked on div that is `contenteditable=true` and upon click I press upload button from navigation to upload image in it. The modal appears and image should upload in desired clicked div.

The problem is I am unable to upload image in that specific div which I clicked as modal appears and image get should get uploaded.

I accomplished this using `window.element` but it is not working now, saying:

`TypeError: window.element is undefined`

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#titleDescImage", function () {
        $('#titledescImgModal').modal('show');
    });

    $("#titledescImg-input").change(function () {
        $('#titledescImgModal').modal('hide');
        readImage(this, 'titledescImg');
    });

function readImage(input, check) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var FR = new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function (e) {
       if (check == 'titledescImg') {
                html = window.element.find("p").html();
                window.element.html(html + "<img src=" + e.target.result + " width=100 height=100/>");
            }
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

HTML is:

```
    <div contenteditable="true" id="website-title" data-attr="heading"
 class="hidden-xs textEditor titleImg"><p style="text-align:center"><span
 style="font-size:36px"><span style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0)">Mohsin Site</span>
</span><br type="_moz"></p></div>
```

Modal HTML is:

```
<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="titledescImgModal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block; padding-right: 13px;">
    <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Upload Image</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="file" id="titledescImg-input">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Button HTML:

```
 $('<button class="btn btn-default" id="titleDescImage" type="button"
 style="border-radius: 4px;float: right;margin-right: 45px;margin-top: 
-45px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></button>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `window.element`. I guess you were looking for `window.document`. Also since you are already using jQuery, why don't you code like this :

```
var html = $(".textEditor.activeNow p").html();
$(".textEditor.activeNow p").html(html + "<img src=" + e.target.result + " width=100 height=100/>");
```

Or just append like this -

```
$(".textEditor.activeNow p").append("<img src=" + e.target.result + " width=100 height=100/>");
```

You need a click/focus event handler to know which textEditor is active

```
$('.textEditor').on('click',function() { //You can use 'focus' in place of 'click'
    $('.textEditor').removeClass('activeNow');
    $(this).addClass('activeNow');
});
```

Comment: For `html = window.document.find("p").html();`. Now, it says, `TypeError: window.document.find is not a function` is not a function. I need to append that in clicked div element therefore I did this. I used `window.element` so my image will upload in that div only. It was helping me for getting clicked html div content.

Comment: Yes, there is no such function. `find()` is available in jQuery. You can try like this `$(window.document).find()`

Comment: I showed above the example how to do it in jQuery. `$("p")` is equivalent to `$(window.document).find("p")` , So I just wrote the shorter one.

Comment: I used that but it append to any p tag in document I need to append it in parent clicked div only. Like modal appears and so that image will get upload to that clicked div only.

Comment: Can you add the html in your question. It will make the problem more clear and solvable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97596/discussion-between-tareq-mahmood-and-learningror).